# Is it possible to implement `max` efficiently on the untyped lambda calculus?

Tags: functional-programming, lambda-calculus, caramel

`min` is usually defined on the untyped lambda calculus as (using [Caramel's syntax](https://github.com/maiavictor/caramel)):

```
sub a b   = (b pred a)
<=  a b   = (is_zero (sub b a))
min a b   = (<= a b a b)
```

This is terribly inefficient. `Sub` is quadratic, since it applies `pred` (which is linear) `b` times. There is a much more efficient implementation of `min` as:

```
min a b succ zero = (a a_succ (const zero) (b b_succ (const zero))))
    a_succ pred cont = (cont pred)
    b_succ pred cont = (succ (cont pred))
```

This zips through both numbers in a continuation-passing style until the first zero is reached. Now, I'm trying to find a `max` that is as efficient as `min`, that has the following properties:

1. `a` and `b` are used at most once on the body of the function.
2. It has a beta normal form (i.e., doesn't use fixed-point combinators is strongly normalizing).

Does such `max` definition exist?

Comment: I remember Loic Colson investigated this kind of problems: System T, call by value and the minimum problem, TCS 206, 1998. I had a look but could not find anything specific about max.

Comment: @AndreaAsperti ah turns out the problem isn't that hard, let me answer it

Comment: @AndreaAsperti oh just noticed I asked `a` and `b` to be used only once. Damn me and my demanding questions.

Answer (score 1):

Just for the records, if `a` and `b` can be used twice (i.e., it would involve a `dup` node on interaction nets), there is a simple solution:

```
true a b  = a
false a b = b
const a b = a

-- less than or equal
lte a b = (go a true (go b false))
    go  = (num result -> (num (pred cont -> (cont pred)) (const result)))

min  = (a b -> (lte a b a b))
max  = (a b -> (lte a b b a))

-- A simple test
main = (max (max 3 14) (max 2 13))
```

But I demanded no duplication (i.e., `lte a b b a` isn't allowed) so I still don't know if that is possible.